# Problemas de conexión con API REST desde WebApi

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

Estoy teniendo un problema al conectarme a un Api Rest desde mi WebApi para extraer información (peticiones get).

He probado a hacer una petición desde un cliente Rest (Fiddler de Telerik) y funciona correctamente, incluso si pongo la url con los parámetros en el Chrome, me da también la respuesta correcta.

Después, cuando intento hacer el Get desde mi WebApi (c#), usando la clase `HttpClient`, me dice que **no se puede resolver el dominio**, así que lo puse en el archivo hosts de Windows y la respuesta cambio. Ahora me dice que **no se puede conectar con el servidor remoto**.

Para descartar posibilidades, me he creado un proceso de consola y he copiado, tal cual, el código que hace la petición, y desde el proceso de consola sí que tengo la respuesta, lo que me hace pensar que, con seguridad, es el usuario del iis (o el propio iis) quien me provoca los problemas.

¿A alguien le ha pasado lo mismo alguna vez? ¿Me pueden decir como puedo solucionarlo?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por aclarar, si sirve de ayuda, estoy haciendo las peticiones desde dentro de la red de mi empresa, saliendo a través de un proxy... No se si el problema puede por el proxy, pero es raro porque la aplicación de consola hace bien la peticion pero el webapi desde mi iis da el error.

Comment: No conozco mucho C#, pero se me ocurren algunas cosas: 1. La documentación de HttpClient dice que tienes que indicar forzosamente el puerto en la URL. 2. Puedes tener problemas con un certificado SSL autofirmado, o bien, un servidor SSL mal configurado. Fíjate en [este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251689/make-https-call-using-httpclient#22251844) para forzar la aceptación de un certificado de este tipo. 3. Tendrás arriba el Firewall? Prueba desactivarlo momentaneamente. Es probable que tu aplicación interfiera con reglas de salida. Si el problema fue de este tipo, deberás ento

Comment: Pero el problema es ¿porque me falla al hacer la petición desde mi webapi y no falla al hacerlo desde un proceso de consola? Ambos estan en mi equipo... si diera problema el ssl o el firewall entiendo que daria tanto desde webapi como desde consola no ??? el código de la petición es el mismo en ambos escenarios, pero en uno funciona y en otro no...

Comment: Coloca el código que estás usando para hacer el request.

Comment: El codigo es muy simple, solo creo un objeto de tipo HttpClient y hago un GetAsync, esto me funciona desde una aplicacion de consola pero no desde un WebApi que se ejecuta en mi IIS local

Comment: Cual es el servicio al que tienes que hacer el request? Puedes poner un ejemplo de como hacesel llamado en el Fiddler? en la aplicación de consola utilizas también HttpClient? puedes poner ese código?